# How to split dataframe columns into a new row or another row?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have output data that's all in one row. I would like to put some into 2nd or other rows. Example

```
1/2023 2/2023 3/2023 4/2023 5/2023 6/2023 7/2023 8/2023 9/2023 10/2023 11/2023 12/2023
```

I would like to transform the above into this result:

```
1/2023 2/2023 3/2023 4/2023 
5/2023 6/2023 7/2023 8/2023 
9/2023 10/2023 11/2023 12/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an input Series of an arbitrary length, craft a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['1/2023', '2/2023', '3/2023', '4/2023',
               '5/2023', '6/2023', '7/2023', '8/2023',
               '9/2023', '10/2023', '11/2023', '12/2023'])

COL = 4

out = (s.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((s.index//COL, s.index%COL)))
        .unstack()
      )
```

If the length is a multiple of the desired number of columns, use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(s.to_numpy().reshape(-1, COL))
```

Output:

```
        0        1        2        3
0  1/2023   2/2023   3/2023   4/2023
1  5/2023   6/2023   7/2023   8/2023
2  9/2023  10/2023  11/2023  12/2023
```

*NB. if the input is a DataFrame `df` with a single row, replace `s` by `df.iloc[0]` and `s.index` by `np.arange(df.shape[1])` in the above code.*

Comment: Thank you for your response. The data is mostly concerned with formatting one giant row into 6 separate rows. Each row is a separate group of category and I have 6 categories so I need 6 rows in which each row displays it's own set of data for its own category. Example

Aquarius: date 1 date 2 date 3
Virgo: date 1 date 2 date 3 date 4 date 5 date 6 
Pisces: date 1 date 2

Comment: Please give the method above a try, if you don't manage to get it to work, please provide code to reproduce your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

`divmod()` is an option:

```
#using same series in mozway's answer

s = pd.Series(['1/2023', '2/2023', '3/2023', '4/2023',
               '5/2023', '6/2023', '7/2023', '8/2023',
               '9/2023', '10/2023', '11/2023', '12/2023'])

s.set_axis(list(divmod(s.index,4))).unstack()
```

Output:

```
        0        1        2        3
0  1/2023   2/2023   3/2023   4/2023
1  5/2023   6/2023   7/2023   8/2023
2  9/2023  10/2023  11/2023  12/2023
```

Comment: is there a way to specifically specify 6 rows and define what columns go into each row?